# Why does HotelSearch return an ERR.NGHP-DISTRIBUTION.INTERNAL_ERROR?

Tags: sabre

I am trying to use the HotelSearch REST api. I have tested it on the Dev Studio website by Sabre and while it is slow to respond it works on a Chrome browser. I then tried to get his working in the sample app Rest2SG Sabre provide, as well as Postman. However it returns this error on both platforms:

Here is the method I have added to the sample app:

```
private void getHotelSearch()
    {
        Job job = new Job("Getting HotelSearch")
        {

            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
            {
                setText("Waiting for response...");
                toggleAllButtons(false);

                try
                {
                    Rest2SgRequest request =
                        lockId > 0 ? new Rest2SgRequest(lockId) : new Rest2SgRequest();

                    // for the list of available service action names
                    // please refer to REST documentation
                    // this same as action in redapp.xml authorization
                    request.setUrl("/v2.0.0/hotel/search");

                    //request.setHeaders(getContentDescription())

                    // previously generated document, normally developer will
                    // have to prepare one by himself
                    String payload = getRequestBody("sample.json"); // we
                                                                    // preload
                    request.setPayload(payload);
                    request.setHttpMethod(HTTPMethod.POST);
                    request.setContentType("application/json");
                    request.setAuthTokenType(AuthTokenType.SESSIONLESS);
                    

                    Rest2SgServiceClient client = new Rest2SgServiceClient(COM);
                    ClientResponse <Rest2SgResponse> rsp = client.send(request);
                    LOGGER.info("Rest2Sg request processing success: " + rsp.isSuccess());

                    if (rsp.isSuccess())
                    {
                        // check if processing ended in with success
                        Rest2SgResponse response = rsp.getPayload();
                        String responseBody = response.getResponseBody();
                        response.getResponseCode();
                        response.getResponseHeaders();

                        setText(responseBody);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printErrors(rsp.getErrors());
                        System.out.println(rsp.getErrors().toString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                toggleAllButtons(true);
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };

        job.schedule();
    }
```

Here is the sample JSON:

```
{
  "HotelSearchRQ": {
    "POS": {
      "Source": {
        "PseudoCityCode": "43X5"
      }
    },
    "SearchCriteria": {
      "MaxResults": 20,
      "SortBy": "DistanceFrom",
      "SortOrder": "ASC",
      "TierLabels": false,
      "GeoSearch": {
        "GeoRef": {
          "Radius": 2,
          "UOM": "MI",
          "RefPoint": {
            "Value": "DFW",
            "ValueContext": "CODE",
            "RefPointType": "6",
            "StateProv": "TX",
            "CountryCode": "US"             
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the error below?

[Error [code=400, description={"errorCode":"ERR.NGHP-DISTRIBUTION.INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"Error occurred while invoking service restish:convertToOutputFormat:1.71.3","status":"Incomplete","type":"Application","timeStamp":"2022-06-20T21:00:51-05"}, type=HTTP]]

As I mentioned this JSON works [on their website](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/hotel/search/get_hotel_search/reference-documentation#/HotelSearch/hotelSearch).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by missing header information. The following line needs to be added to the request:

```
request.setHeaders("{\"Accept\": \"application/json\"}");
```